# Maven - POM design for more module with unique libs module

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I want to configure Maven POMs for a Java standard project, and I want to design the following modules architecture:

- **`Parent` project**: this project builds all submodules.
- **`JAR` project**: this project creates a final JAR file.
- **`Core` project**: this is a main project, but there will be similar projects.
- **`Libs` project**: this is a project that include all library dependencies that will be used by the various main modules (such as the `Core`).

I have a problem to compile the Core module when I refer to a library that I define in `Project-Libs`'s dependency.
(In the following particular example I have a compilation error when I import the JUnit library in a `Core` class test).

The Maven POM that I configure are the following:

#### Parent `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
<artifactId>Project</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>../Project-Libs</module>
    <module>../Project-Core</module>
    <module>../Project-JAR</module>
</modules>
```

#### `Project-Libs` `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <relativePath>../Project</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>Project-Libs</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

#### `Project-Core` `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <relativePath>../Project</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>Project-Core</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Project-Core</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>Project-Libs</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

#### `Project-JAR` `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <relativePath>../Project</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>Project-JAR</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Project-JAR</name>

<dependencies>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>Project-Core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>Project-Libs</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>

        <!-- download source code in Eclipse, best practice -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Set a JDK compiler level -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>

                <modules>
                    <module>
                        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
                        <artifactId>Project-Libs</artifactId>
                    </module>
                    <module>
                        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
                        <artifactId>Project-Core</artifactId>
                    </module>
                </modules>

                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Please, can you help me figure out and mistakes? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you show the directory structure of your project? Apart from that maven-jar-plugin does not know anything about "modules" ?

Comment: Please supply the full error message and the output of `[ ... Project]$ mvn dependency:tree`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd abandon this `Project-Libs` project since apparently it is just there to hold the `<dependency>` settings for your other project. This can be done in the parent `Project` POM just as well. And by outsourcing these dependencies to a separate POM you miss what parent POMs do for you by design: handing down POM settings, e.g. `<dependencies>`, to child projects. Such this extra `Project-Libs` project pollutes all of your other POMs with its `<dependencies>` setting unnecessarily.

I'd design the parent `Project` POM like:

```
  ...

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    ...
  <dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    ...
  </dependencies>

  ...
```

From a certain point of view it sounds also logically that the dependency declared in `Project-Libs` isn't found by your other projects. `Project-Libs` is not a parent, it is a dependency to them. Maven handles transitive dependencies well, but I got to know it trying to be as efficient as possible, too. Now, since a project of type `<packaging>pom` doesn't contain any code to be compiled, tested, packaged, installed and deployed it could be that dependencies in such a project are simply ignored, regardless of any transitivities that are introduced by sibling projects.

You can also introduce a [BOM (bill of material) POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies) as parent to your `Project` parent.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [DependecyManagement](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) in the parent pom.xml file instead.